# How to wait for Python subprocess.check_output() to complete?

Tags: python, subprocess, wait

I am running this code in a loop - in Python 3.6:

```
# previous code: copy certain files to the working folder
    shellCmd = "myCmd " + file1 + " " + file2

# myCmd works on file1 and file2  
    result = subprocess.check_output(myCmd, shell=True)

# delete the files
```

Every now and then I get a fail caused by access denied to some of the files. I am guessing that the subprocess is running in the background and the loop continues, spawning other subprocesses. Sometimes this will cause one subprocess trying to copy (or delete) files that myCmd is still busy with in another subprocess.

How do I stop and wait for subprocess.check_output() to complete?

I saw that subprocess.Popen has a wait() function, but I need the result string from the myCmd process, so want to use subprocess.check_output().

But any solution that will (a) get me the string output of myCmd and (b) ensure the subprocesses happen in series,  is OK.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The situation you describe is far from satisfactory, because it appears that multiple subprocesses will, if I understand your description correctly, sometimes create race conditions. The logical thing to do would be to have your program read the output from the subprocess as it appears.

If you want better control over subprocesses your are safer using `subprocess.Popen` objects, which have a more usable interface. By reading the output from one command until you get to end-of-file you know that you won't be creating additional processes to interfere. Send the command's standard output to a pipe with `stdout=subprocess.PIPE` and then you can read the process's standard output as the `Popen` object's `stdout` attribute as shown below.

```
>>> process = subprocess.Popen("getmac", stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
>>> for line in process.stdout:
...     print(line)
...
b'\r\n'
b'Physical Address    Transport Name                                            \r\n'
b'=================== ==========================================================\r\n'
b'94-C6-91-1B-56-A4   \\Device\\Tcpip_{023B9717-B878-43D4-A0BE-28A4295785FA}      \r\n'
b'68-EC-C5-52-14-AD   Media disconnected                                        \r\n'
b'68-EC-C5-52-14-B1   Media disconnected                                        \r\n'
b'0A-00-27-00-00-0E   \\Device\\Tcpip_{89DD54F9-0C99-4F5B-8376-45598FB4C0FD}      \r\n'
>>>
```

Comment: thanks! Possibly (probably?...) something else going on as tripleee indicated, but using Popen allows me to call wait() to be double sure.

Answer (score 1):

No, `check_output` only returns after the subprocess has finished running. Your problem is caused by something else.